# Get textarea value inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, textarea

I can get text from the `textarea` with my current code. But I want to get it when the `textarea` contained in an iframe, is that possible?

My current code is

```html
<script>
function get_text() {
   var value = $('textarea').val();
   $('#show_value').html(value);
}
</script>
<textarea></textarea>
<div id="show_value"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="get_text()">Click me to show text</a>
```

I tried editing that code like the code below but it didn't work

```html
<script>function get_text() {
   var value = $('iframe textarea').val();
   $('#show_value').html(value);
}
</script>
<iframe src='http://check0909.vv.si/s.html'></iframe>
<div id="show_value"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="get_text()">Click me to show text</a>
```

You can see my demo at here http://check0909.vv.si/

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put like a name and an id and you should be able to use something like this.

```
$('iframe[name=select_frame]').contents().find('#select_name').val();
```